# How to implement cross/nested random effects in lme4?

Tags: lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I am trying to examine "homophily" in school students. That is, I am examining whether pairwise similarity in various traits correlates with closeness in social networks.

Each row of my spreadsheet contains data for following columns: `child_1_id`, `child_2_id`, social closeness of child_1_id and child_2_id, pairwise similarity in trait of interest of child_1_id and child_2_id. This repeats for all pairwise combinations of children. The simplest form of my model is therefore the following:

```r
trait similarity ~ social closeness + (1 | child_1_id) + (1 | child_2_id)
```

However, multiple classrooms were included in the study. I would therefore like to nest within classrooms. Importantly, trait similarity and social closeness were only calculated for children in the same classroom as each other, and therefore `child_1` and `child_2` are always from the same classroom.

How do I go about nesting the crossed random effects for child id within a term for classroom?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just add a random effect `(1|classroom)` to your model, provided your IDs for children are uniquely coded (i.e. your children are coded `1 .. n_children` rather than `1 ... n_1, 1 ... n_2, 1 ... n_3, ...` where `n_i` is the number of children in the `i`th classroom)

If children were *not* uniquely coded you could use a random effect of the form `(1|classroom) + (1|family:child_1_id) + (1|family:child_2_d)`